# How do I install Geforce GTX 660 in 13.10

Tags: nvidia

Just bought a Geforce GTX 660 and replaced my Radeon HD 5870 (it finally died after 3 years). I'm having terrible problems getting the video card to work. As I only had command line options so far I've ran: 
(purged fglrx*)

then

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331

and then I started getting low graphics mode errors. did some searching on my tablet, and I tried several things but what finally worked better was:

sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia

However now that I'm logged into my computer finally, I have no access to terminal, no access to the top bar, and hitting Super Key does nothing, alt-f2 does nothing, and I only can post because I tried running WoW and it had an error and the error report opened a link.

All I can see on my desktop is my wallpaper and desktop icons. I can CTRL+ALT+F1, and navigate to the downloaded official nvidia driver, however that won't run because of x-server, and I can't run it from my desktop.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Just a word of advice - do not use xorg-edgers ppa with this card. I just have recovered from major crash with exactly same hardware configuration. X-spat may be better choice, I have not experienced any difficulties here.

Comment: Marked as duplicate of one that will actually solve your problems. Specially now that correct drivers are available for it and there is no need to manually update them every time a kernel changes.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Downloaded the official nvidia driver, then CTRL+ALT+F1. Logged in, then went to the Downloads directory and typed:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo chmod a+x NVIDIA-*.run
sudo ./NVIDIA*.run
sudo reboot
```

as per:
http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-the-Latest-NVIDIA-331-20-Drivers-in-Ubuntu-13-10-399182.shtml

Comment: And now you have to repeat this procedure every time kernel or anything upgrades.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino I have a script that does it so it's no problem for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

Executing `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` should make it.

Please note that the `nvidia-current` package is located in the `restricted` repository.
If the package is not found. Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and remove the leading `#` character, of the following line

```
#deb http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted
```

Save the file and execute `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

It should work

Comment: I tried that among many of my attempts, and that did not work.